# Terraform GKE node pools always use the wrong service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

On GKE Terraform (this is true when using the web console too), despite overriding the default service account, the creation fails due to permissions. Looking at the logs, it's clear that it's using some default service account for the *default* node pool that has long since been deleted.

```
[PERMISSIONS_ERROR]: Instance 'gke-k8s-failover--default-pool-123' creation failed: Required 'compute.disks.create' permission for 'projects/1234/zones/us-west2-a/disks/gke-k8s-failover--default-pool-123' (when acting as '1234@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com');
```

My terraform config overrides this in the `node_config`, but it seems to not do anything:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "k8s-failover-cluster" {
  name                     = "k8s-failover-cluster"
  project                  = var.project
  location                 = var.region
  remove_default_node_pool = true

  node_config {
    # Default behavior uses the default svc account, so we override
    # to have deterministic behavior w.r.t permissions
    service_account = data.google_service_account.gke_svc_acct.email
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    ]
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [node_config]
  }


  # this will no-op based on config and leverage the node pools
  # defined in node-pools.tf
  initial_node_count  = 1
  network             = var.cluster_network
  subnetwork          = var.private_subnet_name
  deletion_protection = false
  networking_mode     = "VPC_NATIVE"

  addons_config {
    # Disable HTTP load balancing addon since we'll use ingress
    http_load_balancing {
      disabled = true
    }
    horizontal_pod_autoscaling {
      disabled = false
    }
  }

  # Only receive updates from well-tested releases
  # to avoid have sketchy setup
  release_channel {
    channel = "REGULAR"
  }

  workload_identity_config {
    workload_pool = "${var.project}.svc.id.goog"
  }

  # Separates pods and services by their respective subnet ranges.
  # See: networking.tf for CIDR range
  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = "k8s-pod-range"
    services_secondary_range_name = "k8s-service-range"
  }

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_nodes = true
    # Allow access over public IP to control plane nodes (ie. kubectl usage)
    enable_private_endpoint = false
    master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "172.16.0.0/28"
  }
}
```

Losing my mind here not sure if this is a GCP bug or if my configuration is off. I've even tried to override this on the web console. No matter what I do, it uses this non-existent default service account for the default node pool.

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing service account for "Google-managed service account used to access the APIs of Google Cloud Platform services"

Resolution:

**Revert Deletion:** If the deletion occurred recently and the option to revert is available in the Google Console, please revert the deletion.

**Disable and Enable Compute Engine Service:** Disable and then enable the Compute Engine service to recreate the required service account. Manually creating a service account with the same name will not be effective.

Utilize a Different Project: Use a different project that still has the required service account.

Clarification:

The configuration mentioned in the **"node_config" section is associated with the service account used by your node pool nodes**. It is distinct from the service account used to create the node pools. Google recommends attaching a custom service account to the nodes instead of using the default Compute Engine service account.